# Does devise_for :users, class_name: 'Account' work even if there is a User model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I could probably set this all up to figure it out myself maybe, but I really want to know if devise_for :class_name is a good idea in my project.

We have a legacy Users table that has nothing to do with the website user so we can't name our new site user model that. But we still would like to use the customary current_user and associated helpers in our app.

Devise has this handy way of doing this according to the docs:

```
* class_name: set up a different class to be looked up by devise, if it cannot be properly found by the route name.

    devise_for :users, class_name: 'Account'
```

But it's not clear if it looks for the model first or defers to the :class_name if present, or if there are any issues that would bite us eventually with this implementation that wouldn't be obvious immediately.

So in a nutshell, can I use (or should I not)

```
devise_for :users, class_name: 'AppUser'
```

when there already is a User model and users table?

Comment: That's a routing helper. Do you already have resource routes declared for your `User`s?

Comment: It's a bit more than just routing, though, as it ads helper methods like current_user. But no, there won't be any routes for the User model.